# close all instances of internet explorer

Tags: c++

So I was thinking of a way to go about writing a program that closes all instances of internet explorer.  Would it be better to terminate all iexplore.exe processes using the windows API or enumerate the internet explorer windows and close it that way?  (using enumwindows).

Comment: Can we scale this up to terminating all instances of IE in the entire world, rather than just on your machine?

Comment: I just added the first answer, but it works on desktop only. Does anyone know how to do it on Windows CE or Windows Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393/

You will only need the first 2 IFs from method RecalcText(). Paste there this code:

```
HWND hwndWBA;
pwba->get_HWND((LONG_PTR*)&hwndWBA);
InvalidateRect(hwndWBA, NULL, TRUE);
pwba->Quit();
pwba->Release();
```

It will close all explorers. Not only Internet Explorers, but also folder explorers. Works on desktop (tested on Windows 7).

Comment: This works on desktop only. Does anyone know how to do it on Windows CE or Windows Mobile?